# A positive definite function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, proof-verification

I would be glad if someone could check my proof.

$X$ normed Vector space , $\dim(X) \leq \infty $.

$a \in U$ with $U$ a topological space and $F:U\longrightarrow M^2(X,\mathbb R) $ continuous in a

$$\text{F positive definite in a }\Longrightarrow \text{F positive definite in neighborhood of a}$$

**Proof:**

Let $F$ be positive definite and $a\in U$

$\Longrightarrow F(a) \gt0$.

Since $F$ is continuous and U is an open set $\Longrightarrow M^2(X,\mathbb R)$ is a open set $\Longrightarrow \exists \quad \text{neighbourhood }\mathbb  U\subseteq U \quad \text{with} \quad a\in \mathbb U$

$ \Longrightarrow \exists \epsilon \gt 0: F(a+\epsilon) \gt 0$

$\Longrightarrow \text{F is positive definite in neighbourhood of a}$

Where $M^2(X,\mathbb R):=$ { $\omega | \omega:X \times X \longrightarrow \mathbb R \qquad \text{bilinear forms with}~   \|\omega\|~~ \lt \infty$}.

Comment: What is $M^2(X,\mathbb R) $ ?

Comment: $M^2(X,\mathbb R) $ is just the of bilinear forms on X?

Comment: What is $U$? What's the meaning of “$a\in U$ topologically”?

Comment: What is your definition of a "positive definite function"?

Comment: what gauranti that $F(a+\varepsilon)>0$ because that is what you should prove

Comment: @GuyFabrice yes just the bilinear forms on $X$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $U$ is a topology and $a \in U$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom F is positive definite when $F(v) \gt 0 \forall v$